# Фиксация меню, когда оно доходит к верху, и отключение фиксации по завершению секции

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как сделать, чтобы горизонтальное меню в определенной секции (в середине лендинга), когда доходит к верху страницы стало фиксированное,(прилипало к верху), причем все остальное содержимое проходило под ним; а после окончания секции, в котором находится меню, отключалась фиксация и меню прокручивалось дальше...

Comment: на html и css никак, по любому нужен javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- поставить две "метки": в начале секции и в конце
- cоздать событие на скролл, которое бы вычисляло положение страницы и включало или отключало фиксацию.

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```js
function stickMenu() {
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var sectionStarts = $('#sectionStarts').offset().top;
  var sectionEnds = $('#sectionEnds').offset().top;
  if (windowTop > sectionEnds) {
    $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
  } else if (windowTop > sectionStarts) {
    $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
  }
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  stickMenu();
});
```

```css
div:not(.menu) {
  height: 300px;
}
.menu {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.menu.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Начало страницы</div>
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#">menu item 1</a>
  <a href="#">menu item 2</a>
  <a href="#">menu item 3</a>
  <a href="#">menu item 4</a>
  <a href="#">menu item 5</a>
  <a href="#">menu item 6</a>
</div>
<span id="sectionStarts"></span>
<div>Начало секции</div>
<div>Содержимое секции</div>
<span id="sectionEnds"></span>
<div>конец секции</div>
<div>Конец страницы</div>
```

Comment: описка? `$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(window).scroll(stickMenu);`

Comment: @Grundy, да.... спасибо, исправлено

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень долго искал такое решение! все работает, но в верстке все очень криво, когда я доскроливаю к меню (оно у меня посередине) то оно сдвигается вправо, и когда доходит вниз секци то меню выходит за ее пределы на свою  высоту, и уже тогда исчезает...

Comment: раньше нашел такой вариант но никак не могу разобраться в коде. Здесь пример кода с демо в 4 пункте: http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/09/scroll-block.html

Comment: меню вправо сдвигается, потому что элемент меню более не привязан к своему родительскому меню. Тот уехал за экран, и браузер не знает, как позиционировать. Вам надо отдельный CSS прописывать для `.menu.fixed`

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="menu"></menu>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

js. Необходимо подключить jquery

```
var container = $('.container'),
    menu = $('.menu'),
    ws, as, abh, agh;
function position(){
    ws = $(window).scrollTop(); // отступ верхней границы экрана от страницы
    as = container.offset().top; // отступ контейнера, содержащего меню от страницы
    abh = container.height();
    agh = menu.height();
    if (ws > (as+(abh-agh))) {
        // ничего не делаем, чтобы меню прилипло к низу контейнера, когда прокрутим ниже чем контейнер
    }
    else if (ws > as) {
        menu.css('top', (ws-as+50)+'px'); // тут мы в пределах контейнера, расчитываем отступ чтобы меню прилипло к верху экрана
    }
    else {
        menu.css('top', '0px'); // если мы выше контейнера с меню - прилепить меню к верху контейнера
    }
}

position();

$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    position();
});
```

Наша задача определить попадает ли верхняя граница экрана в облать container и, если попадает то подсчитать отступ top

Comment: добавьте в ответ какую библиотеку вы используете, а так же что такое `DOM.doc.on`, стоит так же добавить пояснения в самом коде

Comment: Прошу прощения, обновил

Comment: а так же стоит добавить разметку для которой применяется этот код. Я имею ввиду html